# jquery this, $this, $element and $('#''+element)

Tags: jquery, this

In cases where I need to use a dynamic id I do the following...

```
var element=this.id
$('#'+element).val(value)
```

But why doesn't something like this work and is there a another way to express a jquery id?

```
(this.id).val(value)
$(this).val(value)
```

And what's the use of creating a variable with '$'?

```
var $elem=foo
```

I realize this is probably jquery 101 but I can't find the answer anywhere probably for lack of knowing what to search for!

Here's a code example I'm working on where $(this).val(value) doesn't work but $('#'+nextInput).val(value) does...

```
$(function(){                                                                                
    $('.copyText').keyup(function(){
        var inputStart=this.id
        var value=this.value
        var allInputTexts=$('#body').find('input[type=text]:enabled:not([readonly])');

        allInputTexts.each(function(index, item){
            var matchingInput=this.id

            if (inputStart==matchingInput) {
                var nextInput=allInputTexts[index+1].id
                //$('#'+nextInput).val(value)
                $(this).val(value)
                //return false;
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: You're missing the `#` prefix to indicate that you're selecting an element by ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this.id).val(value);
```

doesn't work because you have to use a `#` prefix in a selector to indicate that you want to search for an ID. `this.id` just has the ID, with no `#` before it.

```
$(this).val(value);
```

should work, I don't understand why you think it doesn't.

There's nothing special about variables beginning with `$`. But some programmers like to use that as a naming convention for variables that contain jQuery objects rather than ordinary DOM elements or plain values.

Comment: I'm fairly new to jquery and programming in general but I agree that it should work but in the example I just added it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: `if(inputStart == matchingInput)` will only be true when the `.each` loop is on the same element as the one that triggered the `keyup` event. Since `value` contains that element's value, `$(this).val(value)` will set the value to the value it already has. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I just figured out why I'm not getting the result I want from $(this).val(value). As you said it sets the value to the value it already has but I'm copying the value to the next input.  Let me find another example..

Comment: If you can find an example where `$(this)` does something different from `$("#"+this.id)`, the only explanation would be that you have duplicate IDs in your DOM, which is not valid.

Comment: So basically anytime this $("#"+this.id) doesn't return the same id as $(this) it's that they're not referencing the same object? I think sometimes it my also be a case of me not knowing how to format the line of code properly... like this for example... var checkboxes=$("#"+(this.id)+ " input:checkbox:checked").length;

Comment: Yes. And the only way that could happen is if you have duplicate IDs. `$("#"+this.id)` will select only the first element on the page with the ID, which could be different from `this`. I would write your last form as `$(this).find("input:checkbox:checked").length`

Comment: thanks for the lesson... it's all making more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

If this works

```
var element=this.id;
$('#'+element).val(value);
```

then this should also work

```
$('#' + this.id).val(value);
```

and this

```
$(this).val(value);
```

Dollar sign in front of a variable often is used to indicate that variable is jQuare wrapper around a DOM element:

```
var $elem=$(this);
```